# Need Assistance Understanding ls -d command in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to wrap my head around the 'ls -d' command.

I run the command 'ls -d' in any given directory and all I get is a '.'

I run the command 'ls -d */ and I get only the directories

I run the command -ls -d * and I get all files, including those that aren't directories.

The man page just states this:

```
list directories themselves, not their contents
```

Can someone please help explain how this switch is supposed to work?

Comment: BTW -- while I'm answering this, it really doesn't belong here on StackOverflow (which is scoped to questions about software development only). Consider SuperUser, or Unix SE.

Comment: Compare `ls -ld *` and `ls -l *`

Comment: for `ls -d *` vs. `ls *`: with `-d`, you only show the name of each file and dir, not dirs' contents. However, without `-d`, you will get all the contents of each dir, which would be a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things to understand are:

- `ls` lists the current directory, otherwise known as `.`, by default.
- `ls -d` makes `ls` show the directory it's listing, not that contents of that directory.

The behaviors you describe all follow from that:

- `ls -d` showing `.` is showing the directory you're in -- the default target of `ls` with no arguments given.
- `ls -d */` tells your shell to run `ls` with each directory under the current one *passed as an argument*; `ls -d` then shows the entries for each of its arguments, behaving as you report.
- `ls -d *` tells your shell to run `ls` with each entry in the current directory passed as an argument. `ls` then lists one entry for each such argument, not showing the contents of each argument which is a directory name as it otherwise would.